# After clicking "Install Ubuntu inside Windows 7" and rebooting it always asks if I would like to try Ubuntu out or install Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, live-usb

I have downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 and I cannot get it to install. I have put it onto a 4GB SDHC card and set it to boot up.

My problem is that when I try to install, I click on "install Ubuntu inside Windows 7" and it makes my computer restart.  It does absolutely nothing afterward -- it just reboots and asks me if I would like to try Ubuntu out or install Ubuntu.

I used Linux Live USB creator to put Ubuntu onto the SD.  My computer is a weak 1.66gHz Asus netbook. I feel like I'm stuck in this strange installation loop.

Comment: No dice.  It went straight to Windows 7. I went to the boot manager and the only OS available was W7.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to install ubuntu within windows 7 then you should look at [wuby](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) if however you want to use the live distribution you burned onto your SD card then you should choose "install ubuntu" and then if you want to keep your windows 7 partition you should go on to resize it in the partition manager to make space for ubuntu. Anyway have a look at the [official tutorial](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support%5d)